# sql server 2008 reporting design layout

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have set up a reporting tool using sql server 2008 R2 with a single report containing 4 datasets on a single page. Each dataset is basically a table and a chart. I would like to have it set up in such a way as to have two datasets on one page of the report and the others on the next page. 
Is there anyway to format the layout of a single report or would I have to design a second report and call that from the first somehow and if so how do I do that?
These reports will be later binded to a web application using the reportviewer but not sure if this is possible with visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add a page break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434.aspx). You'll maybe need to add an extra rectangle per page to hold the table and chart controls for that page (been some time since I designed a report, sorry)